# Is it possible to create faceted search in CT using product attributes?

Tags: java, commercetools

I am able to create faceted search using variants' attributes:

```
.plusFacets(facets -> facets.allVariants().attribute().ofString(sizeDescriptionAttribute).allTerms())
```

But I haven't managed to perform the same if I wanted to do it using products' attributes mixed with variants' attributes.

Is it possible to perform such operation?

Comment: Hi @Eder, could you please elaborate more on what you are trying to do? What do you mean by products' vs. variants' attributes here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `a -> {}` syntax to build more complex process. In example:

```
.plusFacets(facets -> { 
    Object variants = facets.allVariants().attribute().ofString(sizeDescriptionAttribute).allTerms();
    Object products= searchForProducts(fecets);
    return mixOf(variants, products);
}).doMoreStuff();
```

So this whill give you a mix. You just need to implement missing methods or use similar syntax.